Vk_api Python Бот не отвечает на сообщения
Вроде ошибок я не вижу,но вк даже по истечении некоторого времени не дает ответа,в config.py записан сам  токен от бота.Хочу чтобы бот хотя бы отвечал на какие-либо сообщения
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from config import TOKEN

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def sender(id, some_text):
    vk.messages.send(user_id=id, message=some_text, random_id=0)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id
            if msg == "Привет":
                sender(id, "Приветствую тебя тут") 

